# FileModeWinding and DrawPath cause odd spikes to appear

Tags: gdi+

I'm using gdiplus to "stroke" a textout.  In certain circumstances, we see a "spike" appearing on the top or bottom of the graphic, and I'm not really sure why.  We can minimize this by adjusting stroke width and font size, but thats not a good solution.  I'm hoping someone can explain the problem to me.

[image: Spikey Bug]

And the code sample generating this 4, its outline, and the spike (unintentional)

```
GraphicsPath path(FillModeWinding);   

      path.AddString(text,wcslen(text),&fontFamily,StateInfo.TheFont.TheWeight,(REAL)minSize,PointF((REAL)ptStart.x, (REAL)ptStart.y),&sf);
      // Draw the outline first
      if (StateInfo.StrokeWidth > 0) {
        Gdiplus::Color strokecolor(GetRValue(StateInfo.StrokeColor), GetGValue(StateInfo.StrokeColor), GetBValue(StateInfo.StrokeColor));
        Pen pen(strokecolor,(REAL)StateInfo.StrokeWidth);      
        graphics.SetSmoothingMode(Gdiplus::SmoothingModeAntiAlias);
        graphics.SetPixelOffsetMode(Gdiplus::PixelOffsetModeHighQuality);
        graphics.DrawPath(&pen, &path);
        }
      // Draw the text by filling the path        
      graphics.FillPath(&solidBrush, &path);
```

Comment: I'm convinced that the Spike on top of the 4 is because of the similarly shaped region inside the four.  Documentation on fillmodewinding seems to point to this.  I have also tried FillModeAlternate, with no change.  I'm not sure how to recover from this problem.  Any suggestions?

Comment: I doubt the fill mode is the issue. Have you tried running it on a machine with a different video driver?

Comment: Yes, I have, same issues.  The above font is Impact.  Problem does not occur with Arial at same font size, stroke width.

Comment: SetLineJoin worked perfectly, who should receive the answer?  Wish I could split it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use [Pen::SetLineJoin](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms535053%28VS.85%29.aspx) on the Pen you're using to draw the outline, and use something other than [LineJoinMiter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms534148%28VS.85%29.aspx).

Answer (score 3):

I agree that the fill mode isn't the issue, I think it is just the pen width used for drawing the outline. For characters that have enclosed spaces with pointy corners (like 4 and 'A'), as the pen width used for drawing the outline gets bigger, the size of the inner shape (the little triangle in the case of the four) gets bigger too.

Eventually the inner shape will get too big to be contained by the outer shape, and will start to poke through, resulting in the artifact you see.

Here is an illustration of a fixed font size (the Impact font again) as the outline width gets bigger. There is no fill here, just a call to graphics.DrawPath():

[image]

The fill operation doesn't care about the outline width, and uses the original shape of the letter.

This partially masks the problem by covering up some of the messy outline. Here is with the fill turned on:

[image]

Something similar will happen with the character 'A':

[image]
[image]

EDIT: calling `SetLineJoin`, as indicated in the other answer, is the way to stop this from happening.

Comment: +1 for explaining clearly what the cause is.  It's like using a huge pen to draw something. Sometimes the pen can be bigger than what you draw.